# html table comes offset; most likely due to *ngFor

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm trying to align the html table correctly but it comes off. The challenge that I have is with respect to the inner loop (modification) which is a list inside of Revision (in other words Revision 'has a' modification list.

While the result on screen are correct, the table is completely off. I speculate the problem is in the 2 *ngFor loop. Any pointer?

```
        <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Revision No</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Username</th>
            <th>Field</th>             
            <th>Old Value</th>
        <th>New Value</th>  
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
            <div *ngFor="let r of revisions">
                <div *ngFor="let m of r.modifications">                 

                    <td>{{r.revision}}</a></td>                 
                    <td>{{r.date}}</td>
                    <td>{{r.username}}</td>                                     
                    <td>{{m.forItem}}<td>
                    <td>{{m.oldInfo}}<td>
                    <td>{{m.newInfo}}</td>                  
                </div>                                          
            </div>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing can go between your tr and td. Put the first ngfor in a tbody wrapped around your tr. Then put your second ngfor on the tr

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a `<div>` at that position inside a table

Use

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let r of revisions">
```

instead of

```
<div *ngFor="let r of revisions">
```

Comment: I placed it on the first *ng and closed it with /ng-container (in the correct position) doesn't work :-( same result

Comment: @adhg glad to be of help :)

Comment: @adhg it's hard to workout without seeing your more up to date code. But there is that random closing </a> that might be causing it. This looks like a general markup issue now (i.e. Unbalanced tags)

Comment: @AndrewJuniorHoward; thanks again! forget about it. fixed!